# Good and up-to-date resources for good practice on designing websites optimized for mobile devices

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile

I know stuff like [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), which makes it a lot easier to handle the optimization for mobile devices/smartphones. I also came across several sites with articles about this topic, but I would love to have something more bullet-proof and up-to-date information about it.

Problem is that the mobile browser steadily change and there are huge differences, also there are many people with just a *theory* and no proper background to it. Are there any up-to-date and looked-after websites or resources I can rely on to optimize my website for mobile devices (in general) on a basis of good practice?

Comment: When you search Google you can set a time-frame to only retrieve new results. The option is found on the left side of the page under "More Search Tools."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these sites helpful:

- Google's [Go Mo](http://www.howtogomo.com) site offers useful resources & [best

  practices](http://www.howtogomo.com/en/#mobile-best-practices) for building mobile-friendly sites.
- [WTF MobileWeb](http://wtfmobileweb.com/) tracks anti-patterns (that you should avoid)
- [Mobile Web Best Practices](http://mobilewebbestpractices.com/)